# FLTK Modal Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, modal-dialog, fltk

I have an FLTK program that has a base GUI and occasionally pops up a window for notifications (a custom function that is very similar to the win32 function "MessageBox"). The window is created when the program starts, and remains hidden for most of the run time. On linux, the show() function works perfectly, the window pops up and is modal and works fine. When compiled with mingw and run under windows, however, the program hangs when the modal window is shown. It seems like it gets focus but never appears. Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

rebuild FLTK 
try again
if not solved

Check ["Known WIN32 Bugs and Problems"](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/osissues.html#osissues_win32) of FLTK

and  [Submit Bug report](http://www.fltk.org/login.php?PAGE=/str.php?U0%20P0%20S-2%20C0%20I0%20E0%20Q)